# Array as a function argument incompatibility

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have defined an 2D array of SKSPriteNode. It is defined as :

```
   SKSpriteNode *arr [17][25];
```

Now I want to make procedure for testing collisions in this array and pass this array as an argument. How can I do it? I tried :

```
   -(BOOL)checkCollisions:(SKSpriteNode*)array
   {
     ...
     return result;
   }
```

but when I call it like :

```
   BOOL collision = [self checkCollisions:arr];
```

XCode protests (incompatibility and ARC problems). Can someone tell me, how to call it (or how to define 2D array of SKSpriteNodes) properly please?

Comment: Why aren't you using `NSArray`s?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to use an `NSArray` object containing `NSArray` objects with `SKSpriteNode` objects. This way you would not have hard-coded limits on the number of nodes and ARC will not have any problems with determining how to retain and release the objects.

Incompatibility complaints is because your arr variable is of type `SKSpriteNode ***` in old style C. If the compiler still complains it would be something like `(SKSpriteNode *)[][]`. The error message is probably helpful for working out the syntax for passing a two-dimensional C array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Objective C are represented by NSArray objects.

```
-(BOOL)checkCollisions:(NSArray*)array
   {
     SKSpriteNode *node = array [x][y];
     ...
     return result;
   }
```

NOTE: Using container access ([]) can cause unwanted side effects. It is better to use the methods associated with NSArray:

```
[array objectAtIndex:0];
```

For a multidimensional array,

```
[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Please read up on using array objects in Objective C [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Objective-C_Array_Objects).

Comment: What "side effects"?  And please tell the OP why `NSArray` is better than plain ol' C arrays.

Comment: After all I will probably use NSMutableArray of NSMutable Arrays :). Thx for help.

Comment: Arrays in Objective-C an be either native C arrays, or instances of Objective-C collections. Also, please clarify what you mean by 'container access'.

Answer (score 0):

a pointer and a multidimensional array are different types (at least in C).

Try specifying the full array (with bounds) as argument for the method

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does. It explains the incompatibility between the pointer passing and array declaration

Comment: Please provide the code and it will be more complete.

Comment: can you be please more specific (add code). Thanx a lot